How to calculate the position of a dynamic item which will be inserted to a container with many other absolute siblings?
i'am using react-grid-layout to set custom layout. while inserting new items into layout, i need to apply a position for the item, but i'm not going to insert it at the end of the container, instead, i hope i can calculate the position where there is enough space for the new item, coz all items are abosolute position, while inserting, the following information are known:

the total share of with of the container, 24 shares. height is unlimit.
the width and height share for each existed absolute item and their position (x and y). eg: {x: 2, y: 10, w: 6, h: 6 }, which means the item has 6/24 share of width and 6 share of height(each share of height has fixed px value). its position is at 2/24 share of container x, and 6 share of container y.
the same information of the inserting item mentioned above in 2 except position. the position is what i need to caculate for.

there must be a algorithm to find out its position.
find out the first approparate position (share at x and share at y) for inserting item.
